# Links within UILabels to Native Functions

Tags: ios, uilabel

As the title conveys, I want to have a UILabel that will contain phone number, address, email, etc. and I am looking for a way to link to native functions (i.e. when a user clicks on phone number, the dialer is launched and when the address is clicked, the Maps are launched). I've tried to research this and seems like UILabels may not be formattable. One way I could do this is to create custom UIButtons, but that seems tedious in terms of scalability, and may not be the best solution.

Just to give some context, the same exact thing is possible in Android:

```
TextView someText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about);

someText.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);

contact.setText("Toll Free: 888-888-8888");
```

Will work just fine and link the number to the phone dialer. It works the same with an address by redirecting to the Maps application.

Is this possible in iOS and if not, what are the workarounds?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the UITextView instead, and check out the dataDetectorTypes property.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using a UIButton and link it to an IBAction for each of the fields? Or maybe you can look into Segmented Control, though I personally don't have any experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

The above link has custom label to your requirement